# Dataproc failing to install oozie package

Tags: debian, oozie, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying below command on google cloud dataproc:

```
apt-get install oozie-client
```

But dataproc is failing to list oozie package in repository.

error:

```
root@<master>:#> apt-get install oozie-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oozie-client
```

Does any one know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but have you tried the canned initialization action for oozie: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/oozie/oozie.sh

Comment: I tried the canned initialization  action. Same problem, and also apt-get install oozie has same problem.

Comment: yea, Same issue with canned initialization script since internally it looks for the same package while executing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this is probably best said *it's complicated*.

oozie-client does not currently compile against Hive 2 and Spark 2. [Newer versions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/dataproc-versions) of Cloud Dataproc are built with Spark 2 and Hive so. Therefore, at this point, the oozie-client is excluded in our build because it's a bit messy.

It *might* work with Pig and MapReduce, though. So, it depends on your use case. Are you planning on using it with Pig/MR or Hive/or/Spark?

[Apache Airflow](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow) has been increasingly used with Cloud Dataproc and seems to work pretty well. Of course, there are some tradeoffs there, such as the fact that Airflow is probably best seperate from the cluster itself, can take awhile to install, and is an incubating project.

(Source - I am the Cloud Dataproc PM)